# What do I need to do to get Django Unit Tests working again in PyCharm after renaming a project and its directory?

Tags: python, pycharm, django-tests

I have several projects open in one window, some of which are different branches of the same project. I decided to rename the directory and project for one of these branches in PyCharm using the Refactor option on the project. After doing so, the Django Unit Tests Run Configuration I had working no longer works. It is still trying to run the tests from the old directory name.

I have not found anywhere in the Run Configuration to specify the directory. The working directory, yes, but that doesn't fix it. I tried changing all instances of the old path to the new path in the workflow.xml file in the root project (which is where the Run Configuration was stored), but that didn't help, and may have messed up other configurations.

Does anyone know where to change the directory for Django tests in PyCharm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Django project root setting does not get updated when you use the Refactor / Rename option, so you'll have to update it yourself. Go to Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Django. Select the project of interest. Just below the `Enable Django Support` checkbox is the `Django project root:` setting. Click the folder, navigate to your project root, and click Apply or OK.

[image: PyCharm Preferences Window]

(Note that while there are other questions with the same or similar answers, the questions being asked are different enough that neither Google searches nor SO searches found them, thus I chose to document the answer in a way that someone else can find the answer.)